# trying to encrypt/decrypt field in MySQL get 500 error

Tags: php, mysql, encryption, mcrypt

I'm trying to decrypt a field that encrypted fine. When I tried to decrypt it, I get an error 500 Internal Server Error. This my first time working with encryption with MySQL So I'm sure I'm missing something. Here's the code

```
    $mysqli = mysqli_connect(###SETTINGS HERE#####);
    $job_sql = "SELECT * FROM apples WHERE id =1";
    $job_result = mysqli_query($mysqli, $job_sql) or die(mysqli_error($mysqli));
    while ($info = mysqli_fetch_array($job_result)) {
      $encrypted = stripslashes($info['enc_text']);
      $org_text = stripslashes($info['org_text']);
      }
    mysqli_free_result($job_result);


    $key = "JARD01776"; //each key is unique to acct
    $decrypted = rtrim(mcrypt_decrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, md5($key), base64_decode($encrypted), MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, md5(md5($key))), "\0");

    echo "decrypted value";
    echo "$decrypted":
    echo "$org_text";
```

I would appreciate any thoughts.

Comment: You need to enable logging and get the actual error message.

Comment: Using a deterministic IV defeats the purpose of CBC and leaves you rather vulnerable.

Comment: Don't call `stripslashes`

Comment: https://twitter.com/corkami/status/425895957138399232/photo/1